# Twig - loop through part of an array

Tags: twig

What I already can do is this:

```
{% for _item in objects %}
    {{ _item.id }}
{% endfor %}
```

or this:

```
{% for i in 0..objects|length-1 %}
    {{ objects[i].id }}
{% endfor %}
```

To loop though the whole array.

What I want to do is:

- loop through a part of an array
- if the end of the array is reached: stop (instead of throwing an exception)

Kinda like this - depending on which is smaller (imagine there are only 5 items):

```
{% for i in 0.. (10 OR objects|length-1) %}
    {{ objects[i].id }}
{% endfor %}
```

What's the easiest/shortest way of writing this?

**EDIT**

Of course, I could test it in my controller and than pass the result as a variable to the template, but isn't there an easier way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the [slice](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/filters/slice.html) filter.

Comment: Would you be able to add an example in addition to just a link

Answer (score 2):

Posting for anyone who may need this in the future.

I accomplished this with the following slice method to get half of the array and then the other half. I needed this to set a class for only the first half of an array, no matter the number (in my case nav sub-items). Remember to update `Array` as needed

```
{% set half_first = Array|slice(0, Array|length / 2) %}
{% set half_second = Array|slice(Array|length / 2) %}
```